# Googlesheets Apps Script removing nulls/blanks

Tags: javascript, google-sheets-api

I have a column of data that looks like this

```
'','','','','',1,2,3,'','','','', ....
```

I would like to set this data up in a new column to look like this (by removing all the preceding nulls):

```
1,2,3,'','','','', ...
```

I don't care about the nulls that come after the data, but the nulls that comes before the data messes up my formatting.

I have this piece of code that I thought would work, but doesn't.

```
  for (var n = 0; n < dateVals.length; n++)
   if (dateVals[n][0] == "") return;
   else (dateVals[n][0] != "")
      Dates[n] = dateVals[n][0];
```

Any support would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to use `''` not `""`

```js
var data = ['','','','','',1,2,3,'','','','']

var arr = []

for (var key in data){
  if(data[key] != ''){
  arr.push(data[key]);
  }
}


console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Thank you. This works. Can you tell me why you used .push()?

Comment: @OdaySalim,you are welcome  just filling the array , you can ignore it and do with that data what you aimed to do